# Gelman Hill textbook- question about linear transformation

Tags: regression, self-study

I am currently attempting to work my way through Gelman and Hill's textbook on regression. I am stuck at the very first exercise. The text reads as follows:

1. A test is graded from 0 to 50, with an average score of 35 and a standard deviation of 10. For comparison to other tests, it would be convenient to rescale to a mean of 100 and a standard deviation of 15.

(a) How can the scores be linearly transformed to have this new mean and standard deviation?

(b) There is another linear transformation that also rescales the scores to have mean 100 and standard deviation 15. What is it, and why would you not want to use it for this purpose?

I can answer question (a) by either using basic algebra and Y=a+bx to convert the scores directly to what is required. Alternatively, I suppose I could convert the data to Z scores and then transform them to the required values.

Question (b) is where I am stuck. I think I might have two different ways to perform linear transformation, as noted above. But I can't for the life of me figure out why I would not want to use one of these methods.

Comment: I bet you want your letter $b$ to be positive.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. In both cases, it appears that my b value is positive (b=1.5). I am sure I am missing something. Is there something else I need to understand.

Comment: In your $Y = a + b x,$ the new sample mean is $a + b \mu$ while the new standard deviation is $|b| \sigma.$ The suggestion is that you would use $Y = 47.5 + 1.5 x $ but not use $Y = 152.5 - 1.5 x.$

Comment: Maybe if you **compared** the _transformed_ scores of students who scored $25$ and $35$ on the original test (one standard deviation below and above the mean), you will understand why it is desirable to have $b$ positive as @WillJagy is pointing out.